# How to make a class that can run multi-threading program?

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I'm making a spelling word game. In which the word fall from the sky and if players type in the correct word, the word disappears.

I've successfully realized it with ncurses library and self defined function.

Now I need to rewrite it with one self defined class.

But It's really hard to figure out how to realized it with only one class in which two threadings are needed! One for the word falling from the sky, and another for the player typing.

Do you have any ideals to realize it?

Comment: There are ways to create threads and do magic on them. But, for us to assist you,you need to post some code.

Comment: @GodMan, Thank you, I'm researching and trying to figure out some raw plan.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need multiple threads for this.  Instead, you can use `select()` to wait for data to read (from the keyboard) on `STDIN_FILENO` with a timeout (upon which you can advance to the next "frame" of animation).